# Error occure when nCipherKM test instalation

Tags: java, hsm

Error occure when I run java com.ncipher.provider.InstallationTest for chek correct instalation provider nCipherKM.

```
> java com.ncipher.provider.InstallationTest
talled providers:
nCipherKM
SUN
SunRsaSign
SunEC
SunJSSE
SunJCE
SunJGSS
SunSASL
XMLDSig
 SunPCSC
 SunMSCAPI

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.loadPolicies(JceSecurity.java:378)
        at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.setupJurisdictionPolicies(JceSecurity.java:323)
        at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.access$000(JceSecurity.java:50)
        at javax.crypto.JceSecurity$1.run(JceSecurity.java:85)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(JceSecurity.java:82)
        at javax.crypto.JceSecurityManager.<clinit>(JceSecurityManager.java:65)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.getConfiguredPermission(Cipher.java:2586)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength(Cipher.java:2610)
        at com.ncipher.provider.InstallationTest.unlimitedStrengthJurisdictionPolicyFilesInstalled(InstallationTest.java:130)
        at com.ncipher.provider.InstallationTest.main(InstallationTest.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Framework jar verification can not be initialized
        at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.<clinit>(JarVerifier.java:228)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: com.ncipher.provider.nCCommunicationException: Error NoUsableModules while opening channel for MessageDigest mech 44 (SHA1Hash)
        at com.ncipher.provider.nCHash.openChannel(nCHash.java:208)
        at com.ncipher.provider.nCHash.updateChannel(nCHash.java:215)
        at com.ncipher.provider.nCHash.flush(nCHash.java:175)
        at com.ncipher.provider.nCHash.engineDigest(nCHash.java:91)
        at java.security.MessageDigest$Delegate.engineDigest(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.MessageDigest.digest(Unknown Source)
        at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.getSystemEntropy(JarVerifier.java:857)
        at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.testSignatures(JarVerifier.java:744)
        at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.access$400(JarVerifier.java:37)
        at javax.crypto.JarVerifier$1.run(JarVerifier.java:222)
        at javax.crypto.JarVerifier$1.run(JarVerifier.java:187)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.<clinit>(JarVerifier.java:186)
        ... 11 more
```

What I do:

1. Copy the nCipherKM.jar file from /java/classes to /jre/lib/ext.
2. Download  Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files from oracle and copy local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar to у jre/lib/security
3. Add to jre/lib/security/java.security nCipherKM provider as first:

   security.provider.1=com.ncipher.provider.km.mCipherKM
   security.provider.2=sun.security.provider.Sun
   security.provider.3=sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
   ...
4. Run:

   > java com.ncipher.provider.InstallationTest

And get eror.

Comment: (1) for Oracle 8u161 up you no longer need to install unlimited policy, it's already there (and for OpenJDK always was) (2) try putting ncipher as the _last_ provider not the first and the test should at least _load_ and tell you what (it thinks) is going on

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your HSM(s) are not Usable, which means they're not reachable, are in the wrong mode, or in an otherwise unusable state:

> Caused by: com.ncipher.provider.nCCommunicationException: Error
>   NoUsableModules while opening channel for MessageDigest mech 44
>   (SHA1Hash)

Run /opt/nfast/bin/enquiry to find out what the state of your module(s) is and fix accordingly.

You have nCipherKM as first in the list (as it says you should in the manual) which means your JVM will go to it for all crypto operations including hashing.